# Detect off course from a MapPolyline on a MapControl in UWP

Tags: uwp, gps, map-directions, uwp-maps

I have a `MapPolyline` drawn on a `MapControl` using anchor points from a GPX file. How can I detect when my position is off of the Polyline? I tried measuring the distance between the anchor points, and if it's off by 20 meters I raise a off course error. The problem with this is on a straight line, the anchor points are really far apart from one another and whilst I am still on the PolyLine, the off course error gets raised.

Take a look at this:

[image]

As you can see I am WAY off course. How to detect this?

Google's JavaScript API for Maps has a method called [**isLocationOnEdge()**](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/geometry#isLocationOnEdge) for exactly this purpose. Is there something like that for UWP?

Comment: You could calculate the distance manually if it's not provided. Take one straight line from two connected points (A & B) out of the polyline and form a triangle with the Location Point. If any angle is >= than 90, the distance is the min of PointA to LP and PointB to LP; if all angles are < than 90, the distance is the perpendicular distance from LP to the line. Then apply the same formula to other lines and work out which one is the shortest.

Answer (score 1):

I solved this issue by porting Google's `PolyUtil` from the Google Maps SDK over to UWP, and it works a treat.

Here is the source code for [PolyUtil](https://github.com/googlemaps/android-maps-utils/blob/master/library/src/com/google/maps/android/PolyUtil.java).